# Scanner can't see integers, BufferedWriter can't write anything

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedwriter

Good evening!
I need to read some integers and do mathematics with them, but my problem is not with algorithm. Scanner don't read int from .txt, and BufferedWriter don't write those ints either. When I try to write it in console, result is 0. What can it be?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File("aaa.in.txt"));
    BufferedWriter fout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bbb.out.txt"));
    int sum = 0;
    int k = fin.nextInt(); int n = fin.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        sum += fin.nextInt() / n * fin.nextInt();
    }

    fout.write(sum);

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

Here is my input

```
5 30
2 32
7 87
4 100
1 27
16 85
```

Well, a lot of thanks to everyone, there wasn't any problems with scanner or BufferedWriter. I just needed double and as mentioned I didn't understand how it works. It's my code after all. Maybe it'll help someone later.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File("aaa.in.txt"));
    BufferedWriter fout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bbb.out.txt"));
    double sum = 0;
    int k = fin.nextInt();
    int n = fin.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {

        sum += fin.nextDouble() / n * fin.nextDouble() / 100;
    }

    fout.write(Double.toString(sum));

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the content of the file?

Comment: And did you try printing stuff to the console? Helps a lot with understanding what your code is doing...

Comment: Getting better. OK now what happens when you debug your program with printlns as suggested by @GhostCat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're misunderstanding what you're writing to `fout`.

[`BufferedWriter.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int)) writes a single character.

The character that you're writing is `0`, because `sum == 0`. Now, this isn't the digit zero, `'0'` (which would be 48), it's the character `'\0'`, the null character, which is the `char` with value zero. This is a non-printing character, so you won't see this if you open the file in a text editor, or just `cat` it on the command line.

So you *are* writing it to the file, it's just not what you expect. If you want to write the digit `'0'`, use `BufferedWriter.write(String)`:

```
fout.write(Integer.toString(sum));
```

Comment: I am glad that this one didn't fit into a comment and you decided to hand over the solution as answer tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the values you are getting from the text file are considered as Strings.
Did you try the Integer.parseInt() method ?
I did some changes to try to access a file and make the sum of all the numbers provided into input.txt (your inputs) and it runs without issues.
Also, in the input file, i have only one integer by line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    BufferedWriter fout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
    int sum = 0;
    while (fin.hasNext())
    {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(fin.next());
    }
   System.out.println(sum);
    fout.write(sum);
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: "I think that the values you are getting from the text file are considered as Strings" No, they're not, because they're being read via `Scanner.nextInt()`. This is basically doing `Integer.parseInt(next())` internally, but you don't need [to bark yourself](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/116650.html).

Comment: ho yes. I understand. Thank you